# How to limit the available bandwidth for specific processes on Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: windows-8, bandwidth, open-source

So, I wish to limit the upload speed of specific applications which lack a built-in control for it and at the same time I'm trying to find a solution that's as organic and long-lasting as possible.

With a bit of searching I found quite a list of opensource bandwidth control software, all of it for linux, and at the same time I'm having trouble finding anything other than free-trial and paywalled-functionality applications for windows, which I do not wish to bother with.

I also stumbled upon some info about it being possible with the use of group policies but not much detail on how to achieve it. 
The computer runs windows 8.1 pro.

---

**tl;dr:** To sum it up, I am trying to **limit the maximum upload rate for specific applications** by either using **opensource software** or **group policies** or by **other means**, as long as they **aren't** **commercial/demo/free-trial or similar type of software**.

Answer (score 1):

A third-party solution is the free
[ASRock XFast LAN utility](http://www.asrock.com/feature/XFast/XFastLAN/index.asp)
distributed by ASRock with its network cards, but which can also be installed for any
other network card.

This program has a different approach - it does not limit traffic to a specific speed
like do NetBalancer or TMeter. Instead, it prioritizes internet traffic so important
programs can have a higher priority. This lets low-priority programs still use
the entire bandwidth as long as no higher-priority program is executing.

[image: ASRock XFast LAN utility]

Here is how to install it on a network card that is not from ASRock :

1. Download the
   [ASRock XFast LAN utility](http://www.asrock.com/feature/XFast/XFastLAN/index.asp)
   Zip file and unpack it.
2. Start the installation `.exe`, which will display the following message :

[image: dialog]

3. While leaving the dialog open, go to the `%temp%` folder and copy away
   the folder `$cfsfx.0`
4. Click the OK button to let the dialog terminate
5. In the saved folder `$cfsfx.0`, edit the file `Install.ini`
   and change the line

   ```
   mainboard_manufacturer=ASRock
   ```

so it reads

```
    mainboard_manufacturer=
```

6. Launch the installer `Setup.exe` in the `$cfsfx.0` folder and cFosSpeed will install.

---

Another third-party product is
[Sophos UTM Home Edition Firewall](https://www.sophos.com/en/products/free-tools/sophos-utm-home-edition.aspx).

This is a very complete product that allows complex rules and defining pools
of executables, with which I have no experience.

For an example of using it, see the article
[Limit Runaway YouTube Traffic With Sophos UTM QoS](https://www.fastvue.co/sophos/blog/limit-youtube-traffic-sophos-utm-qos).

---

Windows has a built-in QoS method (Quality of Service),
which can be defined via the Group Policy Editor.
Strangely enough, it can only throttle outbound uploads from the computer,
so is more aimed at being used in servers.

It resides in *Local Computer > Computer Configuration > Windows Settings*.
Right-click *Policy-based QoS* and select from the menu *Create new policy*.

One can create policies with more detailed conditions via the PowerShell
[New-NetQosPolicy command](https://technet.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh967468%28v=wps.620%29.aspx)
which is part of the [NetQoS commands](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netqos/?view=win10-ps&viewFallbackFrom=winserverr2-ps).

For example, to limit OneDrive.exe to 5,000,000 bps, then update, list and
delete the policy, execute the following commands in PowerShell
run as Administrator :

```
New-NetQosPolicy -Name OneDriveLimits -AppPathNameMatchCondition OneDrive.exe -IPProtocolMatchCondition Both -NetworkProFile All -ThrottleRateActionBytesPerSecond 5OOOOOO
Set-NetQosPolicy -Name OneDriveLimits -ThrottleRateActionBytesPerSecond 9000000
Get-NetQosPolicy —Name OneDriveLimits
Remove-NetQosPolicy —Name OneDriveLimits
```

Comment: thanks for the recommendation. I'm not absolutely sure but I believe that by setting priorities instead of hard limits there would be an issue with other users on the same local network. The lower priorty process would now play well with other programs on the same machine but together they would still hog the entire connection. Is my assumption right?

Comment: I can see in the photo a "TX Limit", meaning "transmit limit", which seems to be the hard limit you are asking for. On my side, I have only verified that the above installation procedure starts well, but have not finished installing the product, so have no experience with it.

Comment: I have added to my answer a second product and a method that is built-into Windows (although limited to uploads).